# Get three posts before a certain date in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

**I was wondering how I can get the last three posts before (and after) a certain date.**

I was looking at query_post but I can't figure it out.

I'm looking to do this in `functions.php`. Ideally, it would return just basic home page stuff.. title, first image, num_comments, etc. I don't need to query the whole article.

**EDIT: I would also like this all done in one function.. there are explanations out there on how to add a filter function.. which I don't want to do. If the functionality could be simply placed in add_filter(...) that would be fine.**

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got'er. Uses AJAX. Thank you for being a baller PHP (inner functions).

```
function ajax_get_next_posts($wp) {
    if(!$_POST['date']) return 'error';

    function filter_where($where = '') {
            $where .= " AND post_date <= '{$_POST['date']}'";
        return $where;
    }
    add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
    $posts = query_posts('posts_per_page=3');
    print_r($posts);
}
```

Comment: You should probably escape your $_POSTed variable.  Try:

global $wpdb;
$where = $wpdb->prepare( " AND post_date <= %s", $_POST['date'] );
return $where;